# Git git rm --cached, commit, then merge

Tags: git

I need to add a file to the gitignore file.

Multiple instances of the repository are present on my server. Can I do this?

```
git git rm --cached file.php

git commit -m "ignore file"

git push origin development
```

Then, on each of the instances:

```
git pull

git merge origin/development
```

Will this work for ignoring the file across all instances of the repository?

Answer (score 1):

on each instances, the result would be the deletion of file.php

[Instead of using pull](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) (which is fetch+merge auto, not a good practice) or merge, you can do

```
git fetch
git reset origin/development
git checkout .gitignore
```

this way, you will get the HEAD version of gitignore and your file will be kept.

if you don't care, you can do the "common way", which is:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/development
```

this is equivalent to `git pull` (so do either the 2 commands, or this single one, but be aware than `git pull` do already a fetch+merge)

Comment: what if I don't care that my file is kept? Are my steps correct?

Comment: basically that's correct. Just completed my answer. use `pull` or `fetch+merge` but don't `pull+merge` (the second one is useless). I added a link on an article about why pull is evil :)

Comment: when I pull it doesn't automatically merge. I have to run git merge origin/development ager git pull

Comment: just do `git fetch` + `git merge` so :)